# Copying files from S3 bucket in one account to S3 bucket in another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have 2 AWS accounts. account1 has 1 file in bucket1 in us-east-1 region. I am trying to copy file from account 1 to account2 in bucket2 under us-west-2 region. I have all the required IAM policies in place and same credentials work for both accounts. I am using python boto3 library.

```
cos = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=COMMON_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=COMMON_ACCESS_KEY, endpoint_url="https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")

copy_source = {
                'Bucket': bucket1,
                'Key': SOURCE_KEY
              }
cos.meta.client.copy(copy_source, "bucket2", TARGET_KEY)
```

As seen the copy function is executed on client object pointing to target account2/us-west-2. How does it get the source files in account1/us-east1? Am I supposed to provide `SourceClient` as input to copy function?

Comment: The `copy` command is sent to the destination bucket who then reads the object from the source bucket. The credentials supplied must have GetObject on the source bucket and PutObject on the destination bucket. Edit your question and show the IAM policies for the source bucket and the destination bucket. Include all error messages. This knowledge base article explains the IAM permissions required: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to perform such a copy is:

- Use credentials (IAM User or IAM Role) from `Account-2` that have `GetObject` permission on `Bucket-1` (or all buckets) and `PutObject` permissions on `Bucket-2`
- Add a Bucket policy to `Bucket-1` that allows the `Account-2` credentials to `GetObject` from the bucket
- Send the copy command to the **destination region**

This method is good because it only requires one set of credentials.

A few things to note:

- If you instead copy files using credentials from the *source* account, be sure to set `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control` to handover ownership to the destination bucket.
- The resource `copy()` method allows a `SourceClient` to be specified. I don't think this is available for the client `copy()` method.